# How to read data from a file

Tags: perl, file-handling

This is my data:

```
4601 000000000002950 000000600537060DB000000000000000 000000600537060DB 46004375010000009000282959900028252890002825280253563562 V4120 20132352013235 1003NN 10 0`.
```

and my Perl program

```
my$string = "4601 000000000002950 000000600537060DB000000000000000 000000600537060DB 46004375010000009000282959900028252890002825280253563562 V4120 20132352013235 1003NN 10 0";
   my $char = substr($string, 0, 2);
   print $char;
```

it prints `46`.

If I have that data in a file `/home/jack/Desktop/Perl_file.txt` how can I achieve the same result using this file data.

Comment: What are you trying to get? `substr($string, 0, 2)` gets the first 2 characters from the input, so that is obviously `46`. What else do you expect to happen?

Comment: Why would you expect it to do anything other than print the substring of the first two characters?

Comment: How get this output using filehandling.that is only my question

Comment: Ah, you want to get the same output when reading the data from a file? Then please edit your question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just asking how to read from a file in `Perl`?

```
# open file for reading
open my $fh, '<', "/home/jack/Desktop/Perl_file.txt" or die $!;
# iterate line by line 
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    # now you can operate on $line. E.g., print, substr, whatever...
    print $line;
    # or like you have in your example
    my $char = substr($line, 0, 2);
    print $char, "\n";
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: Downvote? This is exactly how you should read from a file in `Perl`

Comment: +1, but you should *always*: **use strict; use warnings;**.